# How to work with big data for multiple pages in php

Tags: php, mongodb

I have an issue, and after searching for it I can not seem to find the answer. I'm also not sure what would be a good search term for what I'm looking for either. Forgive me in advance.

My problem is simple and also not. I have a working website, not public, that looks up a large amount of records/documents from MongoDB. I then take the information out of the record that I'm looking for to make a chart/graph. The problem is, I can not figure out the best practice for handling this data. The lookup from the database is expensive due to how many records the page needs to pull, so I would assume there has to be a better way.

Right now, each page calls the database class, which uses the mongodb php connector to pull information from the mongo database. However, each page recreates the class anew and pulls the same information again. How can I make that information persistent for more then one page request?

I don't know if using a session variable is safe or if I can even use it in the first place. Global(s) also seem to me not to be the right answer. If the website was stateful I would just use the class and pass it around, but unfortunately webpages are stateless. Is there documentation I can look for to help me solve this issue? Or has someone ran into the same issue before and can help me solve it.

The site I have found looking for "how to make data persistent in php" is one of php.org site and it states you should try and avoid making data persistent since the engine does not really track the memory usage, and other items of the such. So how do you get memory to last for more then one page request, so you don't have to lookup large amounts of data for each request? 
http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.memory.persistence.php

Once again, I'm not fully sure I'm looking for the right term and there is a good chance I'm not using the right terms in my searches, if so let me know. Because I really do try and avoid making duplicates of questions.

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question would be "caching". You could use a file-based cache (simply store the result in a file) or a memory-based cache like [Memcached](https://memcached.org/).

For example, if the result is an array, you can serialize/json_encode it and save the results.

Comment: yep, found a website to help me also down the path. http://www.xeweb.net/2010/01/15/simple-php-caching/

Comment: Thanks! I can accept your answer in a few. I always wondered what memcached was for.. I have seen it before in PHP.